# get keepass working with mono

Tags: mono

I want to get KeePass 2.18 running on a Mac. As per the instructions I downloaded and installed mono and KeePass Zip Version.

When I try to start KeePass on the command line I get an out of memory exception.

Any ideas to get KeePass working?

```
cnap-b13-01:KeePass ernst$ mono -v KeePass.exe &
[1] 1262
cnap-b13-01:KeePass ernst$ converting method System.OutOfMemoryException:.ctor (string)
Method System.OutOfMemoryException:.ctor (string) emitted at 0x4a6c28 to 0x4a6c4b (code length 35) [KeePass.exe]
converting method (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
Method (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) emitted at 0x4a6c68 to 0x4a6cf6 (code length 142) [KeePass.exe]
converting method System.SystemException:.ctor (string)
Method System.SystemException:.ctor (string) emitted at 0x4a6cf8 to 0x4a6d1b (code length 35) [KeePass.exe]
converting method System.Exception:.ctor (string)
Method System.Exception:.ctor (string) emitted at 0x4a6d28 to 0x4a6d40 (code length 24) [KeePass.exe]
converting method System.NullReferenceException:.ctor (string)
Method System.NullReferenceException:.ctor (string) emitted at 0x4a6d40 to 0x4a6d63 (code length 35) [KeePass.exe]
converting method System.StackOverflowException:.ctor (string)
Method System.StackOverflowException:.ctor (string) emitted at 0x4a6d68 to 0x4a6d81 (code length 25) [KeePass.exe]
converting method KeePass.Program:Main (string[])
converting method KeePass.Program:.cctor ()
Method KeePass.Program:.cctor () emitted at 0x4a6d90 to 0x4a6e52 (code length 194) [KeePass.exe]
converting method (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
Method (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) emitted at 0x4a6e60 to 0x4a6eca (code length 106) [KeePass.exe]
converting method (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_object_new_fast (intptr)
Method (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_object_new_fast (intptr) emitted at 0x4a6ed8 to 0x4a6f3e (code length 102) [KeePass.exe]
converting method KeePassLib.Translation.KPTranslation:.ctor ()
converting method string:.cctor ()
Method string:.cctor () emitted at 0x4a6f50 to 0x4a6fb3 (code length 99) [KeePass.exe]
converting method (wrapper managed-to-native) string:GetLOSLimit ()
Method (wrapper managed-to-native) string:GetLOSLimit () emitted at 0x4a6fd0 to 0x4a702a (code length 90) [KeePass.exe]
converting method (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific (intptr,int)
Method (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_array_new_specific (intptr,int) emitted at 0x4a7030 to 0x4a709a (code length 106) [KeePass.exe]
converting method string:memcpy (byte*,byte*,int)
Method string:memcpy (byte*,byte*,int) emitted at 0x4a70a0 to 0x4a7163 (code length 195) [KeePass.exe]
converting method string:memcpy4 (byte*,byte*,int)
Method string:memcpy4 (byte*,byte*,int) emitted at 0x4a7188 to 0x4a7204 (code length 124) [KeePass.exe]
Method KeePassLib.Translation.KPTranslation:.ctor () emitted at 0x4a7208 to 0x4a7296 (code length 142) [KeePass.exe]
converting method KeePassLib.Translation.KPTranslationProperties:.ctor ()
Method KeePassLib.Translation.KPTranslationProperties:.ctor () emitted at 0x4a72c0 to 0x4a7316 (code length 86) [KeePass.exe]
converting shared method System.Collections.Generic.List`1:.ctor ()
Method System.Collections.Generic.List`1:.ctor () emitted at 0x4a7318 to 0x4a735b (code length 67) [KeePass.exe]
converting shared method System.Collections.Generic.List`1:.cctor ()
Method System.Collections.Generic.List`1:.cctor () emitted at 0x4a7378 to 0x4a73d6 (code length 94) [KeePass.exe]
Method KeePass.Program:Main (string[]) emitted at 0x4a7600 to 0x4a82db (code length 3291) [KeePass.exe]
converting method (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Comment: That should be fixed in the upcoming version 2.19. As soon as that is available, we will integrate in our package. Best regards, Nico

Answer (score 0):

After all I found http://keepass2.openix.be . Installed this mono/keepass combination which seams to work well.

Comment: After some more testing I have to admit, that keepass2 on Mac OSX is pretty much useless. I'm not able to copy/paste passwords in any way.